# New badge suggestion for high negative score

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, badges, badge-request

I think a high negative score in a question shows an interest. It could deserve a badge!

Comment: Badges are to encourage *good* behavior.  Getting something heavily down voted is only very *very* rarely something that comes out of good behavior. We shouldn't be encouraging people to write crap (the 99% case) (or fail to do the proper research to see if the question already exists) to get another badge.

Comment: Ahh - I see what you tried to do here sandoval31 :-)

Comment: @Rory Alsop Yes, obviously, in the stack Exchange world, laws are retroactive! :-)

Comment: Hahaha. U made my laugh dude due to the question score and due to the question topic.

Comment: @Greg At least I could deserve a badge for a funny question...

Comment: @sandoval31 you definitely earn it. I up vote for that.

Comment: How about a special all-season "dunce hat" mandatorily placed on your avatar for a week?

Comment: Here, have a badge.

Comment: If this question was [status-approved], you would get a badge for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The tooltip on the downvote option states:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Once a badge exists then people will try to collect it. I don't think purposely asking terrible questions is something that should be encouraged and / or rewarded.

Comment: I partially agree with that answer. Meanwhile, I think there is several badges which exist without anybody really try to get it deliberately. What about "tumbleweed", "unsung hero" ? For me, it is that kind of badges which makes stack exchange fancy and funny. If the only latitude is to be the best citizen, that is of no interest to me. We are not machines.

Comment: @sandoval31 Those may be fun badges, but they don't encourage *bad* posts. It's incredibly hard to get the Unsung Hero badge. And the Tumbleweed badge requires posting something still on-topic and good, but one that nobody is really able to answer. (Maybe a very niche topic or something).