# Does this site offer bounties or badges for kindness?

Tags: discussion, badges, bounties

Does this site offer bounties or badges for ***kindness***? And by 'kindness' I mean a comprehensiveness of views, an inviting way of welcoming newcomers, a kind and unarrogant way of inciting the other users' curiosity, not getting easily irritated, not leaving caustic comments...

If this is not the case, I think it is a pity, because it seems to me that certain ***kind actions and behaviours*** could be ***universal*** and ***worth rewarding***.

Would it be a motivating concept?

I must say that one of the things that attracted me to this site as a newcomer was the site's injunction to be *nice* to newcomers :) , however *subjective* this call may seem.

Comment: What would those kind actions *be*? Badges are determined on factual information the system holds, none of the things you mention seem to align to that.

Comment: Interesting idea might be to award badge if a user posted at least X comments (e.g. 100) in a time span of Y (e.g. over a year) and none of the comments received any abusive/unkind flag.

Comment: If not, I suggest a 'naive doormat' badge or, maybe, 'Mark of the Month'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The site does not offer bounties or badges for kindness, unless you count posting a bounty on other users' questions as kind, in which case you have [Investor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/investor) and [Altruist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/64/altruist). If you welcome other users by comments, and the community likes this and upvotes your comments, you might eventually qualify for the [Pundit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/pundit) badge.

Yes, gamification can be a really motivating concept, but for some things, it's probably better if they're not. Gamifying kindness would risk causing *insincere* kindness, and that's probably the worst kind. Besides that, I can't think of a way to measure kindness objectively (you realized that yourself) and that's probably the first criterion to see if something can be gamified.

Besides, I'm pretty sure (by looking at the timing) I've got dozens of undeserved upvotes to my posts across the network, just because I helped somebody out. So indirectly, kind behaviour is already rewarded.

Finally, if you're a paragon of kindness and your community knows you are, you probably have an increased chance of winning a ♦ moderator election.

Comment: There could be one more dimension for this in the voting system than the current three (up/down, close, and delete). The crux would be how visible it should be (the acceptance score was removed due to undesirable side effects).

Answer (score 9):

No, there are no special rewards for being nice. Besides feeling good about yourself.

Not being nice however is in violation of the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

> This Code of Conduct helps us build a community that is rooted in **kindness**, collaboration, and mutual respect.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

What is nice is a very subjective call, severely impacted by one's culture. What might be nice for me, could be way to direct for you. Therefore I don't think there is a single objective measure we could implement on the basis of which badges can be awarded.

Comment: Offering rewards for kindness would be aimed not only at making people feel good about themselves, but at motivating all to be competent without being arrogant and dismissive.

Comment: but, ok, fine, it is probably too vague and difficult to pin down.

Comment: 'Not being nice however is in violation of the Code of Conduct', excuse me, I have to go and r/a flag most of the questions on the 'C' tag:(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65206226/758133 unkind no-effort homework dump.  Flag as r/a.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65206171/758133 unkind 'help with something I did not post' . Flag as CoC violation.

Comment: There are plenty more unkind questions.  I have not actually flagged any as 'unkind' or r/a because, as we all know, the CoC does not apply to unkind questions, only to curator comments.

Comment: @MartinJames well I think your not taking faith into account here. These questions all appear to be asked in good faith, while some commenters write benign or snarky comments in bad faith. There is a major difference between those two. Also if you read the CoC page I linked, you see examples covering both curators and new posters.

Comment: @Luuklag software engineering is evidence-driven, not faith-based.  I do not doubt that there are examples, but I doubt that they cover the many cases of exploitation and abuse.  The narrative of evil, hostile commenters writing 'benign or snarky comments in bad faith' is continually driven down our throats, despite the paucity of evidence.  OTOH, unresearched dumps and works requests that treat users as mindless drones are ten-a-penny, and glossed-over whenever 'nice, welcoming' issues come up:(

Answer (score 7):

If you wanted to, you could set a bounty on an answer that you feel is especially kind or welcoming by using the

> **Reward existing answer**
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

reason.

Usually, good questions/answers get upvoted, but I've seen especially helpful or supportive answers gain bounty bonuses.

Answer (score 1):

The Q&A "[How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17853/282094)" explains the motivation behind offering badges (the ***why***), as opposed to the Q&A "[What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/282094)" (the ***how***).

- Badges have three basic [tenets](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/tenet):

1. > "Badges are awarded to users in recognition of their contributions to the community."
2. > "There are three ranks of badges. **Bronze** badges are relatively easy to get, and often help teach users how to use the system. **Silver** badges are more difficult to earn, and can be gained for things like posting extremely insightful questions and answers, as well as a dedication to moderation and improvement of site content. **Gold** badges are the most difficult to earn, and generally signify outstanding dedication or achievement."
3. > "Additionally, certain specific badges can count toward the user's [candidate score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252641/282094) in a moderator election, which is a number shown to election voters that provides a rough indication as to the user's potential moderation skills.

- In addition there are [tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/282094):

  > "These are awarded when you achieve a specific number of upvotes for answers within a particular eligible tag (which is in use on at least 100 questions) ..."

  > "Gold requires an overall score of 1,000 and 200 or more answers."

  > "Possessing a gold badge for a tag will allow you to cast binding votes to close questions as duplicates or reopen questions closed as duplicates, provided you haven't edited the tags or previously voted to close or reopen, respectively.

  > Unlike most other badges, tag badges are revoked immediately if you ever cease to meet their criteria, which can happen if your answers are downvoted, deleted, or converted to community wiki, if the tag is removed from questions that you've answered, or if the tag becomes ineligible for badges because it's no longer used on 100+ questions."

Information on "[What makes a good badge? When and why should I suggest a new badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288251/282094)" explains:

"A good badge proposal:

- Encourages positive behavior.
- Helps sites thrive and promotes an effective Q&A model.
- **Does not** conflict with existing site goals, **contradict existing mechanics**, **create more work for moderators**, etc.
- Often includes a thoughtful analysis of the effects of the badge (both good and bad).".

There is no ***one*** badge that rewards all the accomplishments you have listed. It would seem that such attributes could not be determined algorithmically, but would be opinion based in most cases, that makes them ineligible under the current mechanism of the badge system.