# Badge suggestions: Finder, Hunter, and Detective

Tags: feature-request, badges, duplicate-questions, badge-request

To encourage helpful dupe-finders (regardless of whether they can close vote or flag), I am thinking of the following badges:

(bronze) Finder: Find a duplicate that gets the question closed as a dupe within 5 days of the duplicate being found.

(silver) Hunter: Find 10 duplicates for 10 different questions, such that each question is closed as a dupe within 5 days of the duplicate being found and stays closed for another 50 days.

(gold) Detective: Find 50 duplicates over 6 months old for 50 different questions, such that each question is closed as a dupe within 5 days of the duplicate being found and stays closed for a year.

These badges would encourage the finding of duplicates. To prevent gold-tag-badge holders from abusing their privilege to get these badges, I added the clause that the question should stay closed.

The way that this is different from the [proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5) is that it rewards only duplicate-finding, and it isn't partial to high-rep users more so than other badges. It is also different from the [answer I linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions/65894#65894) in that it provides a way to prevent abuse of the system by gold tag-badge holders, and the Detective badge cannot be earned by easy work like seeing if the same question was asked recently (which it probably would have been were it a homework assignment).

Comment: This has already been discussed: [Reward finding duplicate questions - +10, +2, -5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5). While the question there asks for reputation rewards, the answers there are applicable here, especially the second-voted answer.

Comment: Also, before proposing new badges, I *highly* recommend reading this post: [What makes a good badge? When and why should I suggest a new badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288251/377214)

Comment: It is different, since there are already badges for moderation, so adding more wouldn't go against the purpose of badges.

Comment: Note that I edited my earlier comment to clarify why I'm voting this as a duplicate. The system doesn't load comment edits automatically so you probably didn't see it.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions/65894#65894

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I clarified how my proposal is different.

Comment: Not a huge fan of insinuating that users are *hunting* questions that should be closed or encoraging users to actively seek out dupe closable questions. While performing these tasks are important to the site, it's not one where we necessarily need to be *looking* for things to close, rather, things we come across using the site normally that should be closed should be acted on.

Comment: @KevinB By "hunter" I meant hunting for a duplicate.

Comment: I get that, it doesn't change the name of the badge you suggested...